# How to stop com.seven.Z7.Social Hub from keeping my phone awake?

Tags: permissions, standby

com.seven.Z7.Social Hub is regularly keeping my phone awake for hours and hours. How do I stop it from doing so?

Thank you

Comment: Is this still of interest to you? If so, please provide a few additional details: Is your device rooted? Is it a pre-installed app (as described in that one answer)? Is it an app you are using/depending upon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually just stopped using the app. Not worth my headache. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Yahoo, and have recently changed your yahoo account passowrd, then this will cause the social hub app to get caught in a loop and drain the battery

Delete the yahoo account and recreating it should fix the issue (you may need to reboot and use the phone offline before it will let you delete the account)

Regards

Ian

Answer (score -1):

This app is a Russian application erroneously installed as a "system" app (same package name as the Email hub). If you're rooted you can use something like Titanium Backup to remove the app. Otherwise you can try these instructions from [an Android Authority article](http://www.androidauthority.com/russian-email-application-accidently-installed-on-some-samsung-devices-68331/):

> Removing the application on un-rooted devices seems much harder,
>   however success has been reported by clearing the Play Store’s data
>   and cache from Settings>Applications – Afterwards, just launch the
>   Android Market application to re-acquire the current market state and
>   Google Play application.

Comment: Yes it is, but the asker has a problem with the original.

Comment: It seems kind of unlikely that this would be the issue, though. The incorrect app was put on the Google Play back in March; the OP would basically have had to never use the Play Store since then in order to still have the erroneous app installed. More likely, the *actual* email app is misbehaving.